# Common methods implemented by different classes

Tags: c#, abstract-class

We are working on an application that have lookups methods to the database, now most or some of the classes in my project will use these lookups methods. I dont want to create an interface because that will force my classes to implement all the methods in the interface.
So basically, i want a class that will have  lookup methods that will be commonly used by most/some of my methods.

For example
I have these lookup

```
class lookup
{
public bool getId();
public bool getName();
public bool getDescription();
}
```

I might have classes that will implement only one or none of these methods

```
Class A
{
public bool getId()
{
do some work
}
}

class B
{
public bool getName()
{
do some work
}
}

class C
{
implements none of the methods
}
```

And so on..

how can this be achieved? I am guessing an abstract class, would that be right

Comment: one or more interfaces is the only way to do that. c# does not have multiple inheritance.

Comment: *I dont want to create an interface because that will force my classes to implement all the methods in the interface. So basically, i want a class that will have lookup methods that will be commonly used by most/some of my methods.* -- so.. you want a contract without interface..? that'd be hard.. but then you mentioned abstract.. i have no idea what kind of sorcery you want do but reflections.. and that will be dangerous tbh.. better off, keep on the track with Daniel's suggestion.

Comment: Your intention is not clear as your description is a bit confusing. First you say `I want a class that will have lookup methods` and then `classes that will implement only one or none of these methods`. Can you elaborate on how `lookup` is related to `A`, `B` and `C` and why it is necessary that e.g `A` has a method with the same name as a method in `lookup` (as opposed to implementing `getIdSpecialized` in `lookup`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options, if you dont want to have a plethora of interfaces is to have a default implementation on your abstract base class:

```
public abstract class LookupBase
{
    public virtual bool getId()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public virtual bool getName();
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public virtual bool getDescription();
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And the in your concrete implementations override only what you need:

```
public class LookupA: LookupBase
{
    public override bool getId()
    {
        //do some work
    }
}
```

If you would throw exceptions as in my example, it will be obvious during the runtime that something is not implemented. However, this will happen only during the runtime, and not at compile time. As @Bagus Tesa mentioned this approach will require a lot of discipline and documentation to know what is happening in each case.
Another slightly more safe in terms of execution and slightly more dangerous approach would be to have a default implementation that will do nothing / return a default object of those methods. It wont crush your app during the runtime but will lead to potential logical errors.

Comment: but it may induce unecessary pitfalls as people are not aware that the base class actually throwing things instead of doing actual work... a documentation may solve that a bit, but its counter intuitive and docs are not inherited.

Comment: @BagusTesa - yep. I was about to add this to the answer by myself :)

Comment: Exactly what I was gonna say ... To use an abstract class.

Comment: @JleruOHeP, do you need a default implementation? unless you need one, i think abstract class is not the way to go for.

Comment: @BagusTesa well, this is just my suggestion, it is up to OP to pick his solution. And OP wanted to have a base class without forcing all of his classes to implement all the methods.

Comment: An abstract class whose concrete method implementations just throw not implemented seems kinda silly. Either provide useful concrete implementations or mark the method abstract

Comment: I guess making individual interface seems to be the best way